# Laravel Eloquent display results from multiple tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to create a basic logs program, each log entry is associated to a user using his id, I can't display the whole log entries on a table and use the relationship between the models to display the user name instead of his id in the table, any help is appreciated to explain the syntax and why is the relation not showing.

my controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $dcmlogs = log::with('users')->get();

   return view('dcmlog.index', compact('dcmlogs'));
 }
```

log model:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
    }
```

user model:

```
public function logs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Logs');
    }
```

the view:
  the field users-> is appearing empty with nothing in it.

```
@foreach($dcmlogs as $post)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$post['users->name']}}</td>
        <td>{{$post['description']}}</td>
        <td>{{$post['action']}}</td>
        <td>{{$post['type']}}</td>
        <td>{{$post['comment']}}</td>
        <td>{{$post['created_at']}}</td>
```

and here is my logs table

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

what am i doing wrong?

EDIT:output of dd(dcmlogs)

```
Collection {#220 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => log {#226 ▼
      #table: "logs"
      #fillable: array:4 [▼
        0 => "action"
        1 => "description"
        2 => "comment"
        3 => "type"
      ]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:8 [▶]
      #original: array:8 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "type" => "volvo"
        "action" => "okoko"
        "description" => "okok"
        "comment" => "kokok"
        "user_id" => 1
        "created_at" => "2018-02-27 07:57:19"
        "updated_at" => "2018-02-27 07:57:19"
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "users" => User {#231 ▼
          #table: "users"
          #fillable: array:3 [▶]
          #hidden: array:2 [▶]
          #connection: "mysql"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:7 [▼
            "id" => 1
            "name" => "alex"
            "email" => "ijijij@gmail.com"
            "password" => "$2y$10$fSk7n1JqNTp2bQL/iBfXfOIetXOfpPhLBhu/S3mwp3CeLJi"
            "remember_token" => "lCx9FtWOHEGQmpP1bX9XtxFGdN3vCS6OAxkrO2AAei4ARtlrUa6KpmNG"
            "created_at" => "2018-02-27 07:56:45"
            "updated_at" => "2018-02-27 07:56:45"
          ]
```

Comment: 'users->username'  is a string. You must do it like $post->users->username

Comment: still, the same problem any field which have data coming from logs table is fine, but my only problem is getting the user name from the users table..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get property of `$post` like array but `$post` is a `object`. Change your `foreach` to:

```
@foreach($dcmlogs as $post)
  <tr>
    <td>{{$post->users->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$post->description}}</td>
    <td>{{$post->action}}</td>
    <td>{{$post->type}}</td>
    <td>{{$post->comment}}</td>
    <td>{{$post->created_at}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: just to clarify, in the table, any data coming from the logs table is appearing, but my problem is with getting the username from Users table using the user_id from the logs table.

I have tried your solution and still no luck.

Comment: did you getting logs table data, could you please show us what `dd($dcmlogs)` gives in controller??

Comment: @Abdul everything seems fine, what happen when you try my answer??

Comment: ah thanks for making me look back, i was pointing it to the wrong field, it supposed to be users->name not users->username.